# Customizing layout to sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice disable checkbox

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

Good morning,

In Symfony 1.4,
I tried to do what is explained here : [Customizing layout to sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953970/customizing-layout-to-sfwidgetformdoctrinechoice/16018948)
But it doesn't work. Instead of adding a thumbnail, **I just want to hide the `<li>` before the input, and in some condition disable/hide the checkbox input but show the label anyway**.
When I add the renderer without argument, I get this error :
`sfWidgetFormMySelectCheckbox requires the following options: 'choices'.`

**Here is my formatter code :**

```
class sfWidgetFormMySelectCheckbox extends sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox
{
  public function configure($options = array(), $arguments = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $arguments);
  }

  protected function formatChoices($name, $value, $choices, $attributes)
  {
    .....

      // new
      $inputs[$id] = array(
        'input' => sprintf('| test | %s',
          $this->renderTag('input', array_merge($baseAttributes, $attributes))
        ),
        'label' => $this->renderContentTag('label', self::escapeOnce($option), array('for' => $id)),
      );
    }

    return call_user_func($this->getOption('formatter'), $this, $inputs);
  }
}
```

**And now the form where I call it :**

```
$this->setWidget('aaa', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => 'Aaa',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'add_empty' => false,
    'query' => $query,
    'renderer' => new sfWidgetFormMySelectCheckbox()
  )));
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you have to pass the `choices` option to the `renderer` object. Try something like this:

```
$this->setWidget('aaa', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
    'model' => 'Aaa',
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'add_empty' => false,
    'query' => $query,
)));

$this->widgetSchema['aaa']->setOption('renderer', new sfWidgetFormMySelectCheckbox(array(
    'choices' => new sfCallable(array($this->widgetSchema['aaa'], 'getChoices'))
)));
```

So basically you want the renderer object get the choices from the parent widget. To do that you have to pass a `sfCallable` object which takes an `array` as the first argument in which you pass the instance of your parent widget and the name of the function `getChoices`.

Remember also that the `expanded` option is not used when you override the `renderer`.